# In a Kendo UI Grid with inline edition and textarea, the Enter keypress doesn't work

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, grid, inline, keydown

In a Kendo UI Grid (inline edition) with these lines it's possible to edit a row using the keyboard:

```
$("#grid table").on("dblclick", "tr", function (e) {
    var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
    grid.editRow($(this));
})
$("#grid table").on("keydown", "tr", function (e) {
    var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if (code == 13) { 
        $(e.srcElement).closest("tbody").focus();
        setTimeout(function () {
            grid.saveRow();
        })
    }
    if (code == 27) { 
        grid.cancelChanges();
    }
})
```

However, I need to use a custom editor (with a multiline `textarea` instead of a `textbox`):

```
{ field: "Value", title: "Value", width: "250px", editor: textareaEditor }
...
function textareaEditor(container, options) {
    $('<textarea id="txtAreaValue" name="' + options.field + '" style="width: ' + container.width() + 'px;height:' + container.height() + 'px" />').appendTo(container);                
}
```

And with that modification, the Enter keypress doesn't work anymore. There is a problem setting the focus. I tried to solve it using different approaches, but I couldn't find the solution. Thank you a lot!

**Edit**: This is the Dogo example: http://dojo.telerik.com/@luis.hernandez/inIhUy/3
Just uncomment this `/*, editor: textareaEditor*/` to see the issue.

Comment: What if you change the *keydown* event selector to `"tr, textarea"` ?

Comment: It would be great if you could knock together a Dojo example to demonstrate the issue and could be modified to demonstrate a fix?

Comment: What do you expect Enter to do here?  The textarea wants to use it to add a newline, and your keydown handler wants it to save the row.  Do you want it to just save the row and not add a newline(how do you expect to add a newline then)? Do you expect it to do both(newline and save the row, awkward I think)?

Comment: No @DontVoteMeDown, that doesn't work.

Comment: @Sandman I've just added a Dogo example.

Comment: @TheDreadPirateStephen please see the Dogo example. It's clearer.

Comment: Your example is working for me.. I.e. Hitting enter inside any editable column is calling the `saveRow()` function. What do you expect to happen?

Comment: Hi @Sandman, if you comment this `/*editor: textareaEditor*/` in the example, you can edit the ProductName like an Excel spreadsheet: double click for edit, change the value, hit Enter and the value is modified (updated). However, if you uncomment the indicated code, now when you double click in a ProductName will appear a TextArea. Try editing the text and hitting Enter and the text won't change. The 'saveRow()' is not fired.